# conjunction of and expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let there be
$$a=\cos{π\over9}$$
and $$t=1-8a+8a^2$$
write the expression
$${1\over t } = x
+ya+za^2$$where $x,y,z$ are rational numbers.
I do not know how to eliminate $a$ from the nominator. Does there exist a general technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general method to solve this kind of problem:

Let $K/k$ be an algebraic extension of fields, and $a$ be an element in $K$, with minimal polynomial $P(x) \in K[x]$. Let $Q(x) \in K[x],Q(x) \ne 0$, then, since $P(x)$ is irreducible, $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$ are coprime, we have the so-called Bezout equality: $$\exists R(x), S(x) \in k[x], s.t. P(x)R(x) + Q(x)S(x)=1.$$ Then, replace $x$ by $a$, and notice that $P(a)=0$, we have $$Q(a)S(a) =1.$$ Thus $Q^{-1}(a)=S(a).$

In this case, the minimal polynomial of $a$ is $P(x)=8x^3 -6x -1$, let $Q(x)=8x^2 -8x +1$ and the Bezout equality is: $$(8a^3-6a-1)(-\frac{8}{17}a-\frac{8}{17})+(8a^2-8a+1)(\frac{8}{17}a^2 +\frac{16}{17}a+\frac{9}{17})=1.$$ Thus, $t^{-1}=\frac{8}{17}a^2 +\frac{16}{17}a+\frac{9}{17}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i have only one question.How did you find the forms of R(x) and S(x)?

Comment: It's the Euclidean Algorithm which is used to find the g.c.d. of two elements and to get the Bezout's Identity